# Why does chained function in Parse not work when I retrieve values from database?

Tags: javascript, arrays, function, parse-platform, cloud

In the code snippet below, all the functions are called in the last Parse Cloud code function. It works properly when I test it with the commented part of the getCinemasInLocation functions. That is, when I return an array of object ids manually.

However, when I ask it to retrieve the cinema ids from the database, and use it as its return value in the function, it returns an empty array that looks like this.

```
{"result":[[],[],[],[]]}

function getCinemasInLocation(theLocation) {
// some code
//var result = ["xiUXXYFhAl","Yanh9iDykk"];
//return result;
var result = new Parse.Promise();
var query = new Parse.Query("Cinema");
query.equalTo("Location", theLocation);
query.find({
    success: function(objects) {
        var cinemas = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            var cinema = objects[i];
            cinemas.push(cinema.id);
        }
        result.resolve(cinemas);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        result.reject(error);
    }
});
return result;
}

// This function returns the array of movieIds of a cinema
function getMovieIdsInCinema(cinemaId) {
var result = new Parse.Promise();
var query = new Parse.Query("showing");
query.equalTo("cinema", {
    __type: "Pointer",
    className: "Cinema",
    objectId: cinemaId
});
query.find({
    success: function(objects) {
        var movieIds = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
            var movie = objects[i].get("movie");
            movieIds.push(movie.id);
        }
        result.resolve(movieIds);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        result.reject(error);
    }
});
return result;
}

Parse.Cloud.define("getMovieIdsInCinemass", function(request, response) {
var cinemasInLocation = [];
var theLocation = request.params.theLocation;
cinemasInLocation = getCinemasInLocation(theLocation);


var promises = [];
_.each(cinemasInLocation, function(cinemaId) {
    promises.push(getMovieIdsInCinema(cinemaId));
});

Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(
    function() {
        var result = [];
        _.each(arguments, function(object) {
            result.push(object); // each object is an array of movieIds
        });
        response.success(result); // return array of arrays
    },
    function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    }
);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. I wrapped the entire functions in the callback function of getCinemasInLocation. This is what the calling function looks like now.

```
Parse.Cloud.define("getMovieIdsInCinemass", function(request, response) {
var cinemasInLocation = [];
var theLocation = request.params.theLocation;

getCinemasInLocation(theLocation, function(cinemas) {

cinemasInLocation = cinemas;


var promises = [];
_.each(cinemasInLocation, function(cinemaId) {
    promises.push(getMovieIdsInCinema(cinemaId));
});

Parse.Promise.when(promises).then(
    function() {
        var result = [];
        _.each(arguments, function(object) {
            result.push(object); // each object is an array of movieIds
        });
        response.success(result); // return array of arrays
    },
    function(error) {
        response.error(error);
    }
);
///
});
});
```